# Adding a second INNER JOIN MySQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

How do you add a second INNER JOIN to a SELECT query?

For example:

I have ENTRY with event details (event_id, athlete_id, place) and PRIZE with race details (event_id, place, money).

This is the SQL I’m trying to run:

```
SELECT ENTRY.event_id, ENTRY.athlete_id, PRIZE.place, PRIZE.money
FROM ENTRY
INNER JOIN PRIZE
    ON PRIZE.event_id=ENTRY.event_id
INNER JOIN ENTRY
    ON ENTRY.place=PRIZE.place
ORDER BY ENTRY.event_id, ENTRY.athlete_id;
```

Comment: Aliases are your friend, Beyond that, and if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you make consecutive joins the same way you make your first join.  In your example, everything is good, except you need to alias your tables so that the database knows what you mean.

```
 SELECT E1.event_id, E1.athlete_id, P1.place, P1.money
      FROM ENTRY E1
      INNER JOIN PRIZE P1
          ON P1.event_id=E1.event_id
      INNER JOIN ENTRY E2
          ON E2.place=P1.place
      ORDER BY E1.event_id, E1.athlete_id;
```

This allows the database to distinguish the first Event table (here listed as E1) and the second one (here listed as E2)